# Pulling Docs List from Collection

Tags: collections, google-apps-script, spreadsheet, google-docs

I there a way to display specific collection files and URL in a spreadsheet?

I have already tried running a basic DocList Search script but I need something to be more direct. I would need the script to display File Name, Collections It belongs to, and URL.

The end goal of this project is to create a Google site that allows users to click a Image link launching a simple "Copy Function" this copy function will create a copy of that document for the user in there individual drive. However we will be doing this on a mass scale of over 1,000 documents. So pulling the information and having it more organized would be alot easier then copying the URL section out of each document and then pasting it into the scripts functions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here is a script I wrote quite a while ago that does (a bit more than ) what you want... it shows the IDs but you can easily change it to show the urls instead.

```
// G. Variables
var sh = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var lastrow = ss.getLastRow();
//
//
//
function onOpen() {
  var menuEntries = [ {name: "generic doclist", functionName: "gendoclisttest"},
                      {name: "categorized list(spreadsheet/docs)", functionName: "doclistcat"},
                      {name: "Search DocList", functionName: "searchUI"},
                    ];
  ss.addMenu("Utilities", menuEntries);//
}
//
// Build a simple UI to enter search item and show results + activate result's row
function searchUI() {
  var app = UiApp.createApplication().setHeight(130).setWidth(400);
  app.setTitle("Search by name or folder name");
  var panel = app.createVerticalPanel();
  var txtBox = app.createTextBox().setFocus(true).setWidth("180");
  var label=app.createLabel(" Eléments à rechercher :")
  var label=app.createLabel(" Item to search for :")
  panel.add(label);
  txtBox.setId("item").setName("item");
  var label0=app.createLabel("Row").setWidth("40");
  var label1=app.createLabel("Doc Name").setWidth("180");
  var label2=app.createLabel("Doc ID").setWidth("180");
  var hpanel = app.createHorizontalPanel();
  hpanel.add(label0).add(label1).add(label2);
//
  var txt0=app.createTextBox().setId("lab0").setName("0").setWidth("40");
  var txt1=app.createTextBox().setId("lab1").setName("txt1").setWidth("180");
  var txt2=app.createTextBox().setId("lab2").setName("txt2").setWidth("180");
  var hpanel2 = app.createHorizontalPanel();
  hpanel2.add(txt0).add(txt1).add(txt2);
  var hidden = app.createHidden().setName("hidden").setId("hidden");
  var subbtn = app.createButton("next ?").setId("next").setWidth("250");
  panel.add(txtBox);
  panel.add(subbtn);
  panel.add(hidden);
  panel.add(hpanel);
  panel.add(hpanel2);
  var keyHandler = app.createServerHandler("click");
  txtBox.addKeyUpHandler(keyHandler)
  keyHandler.addCallbackElement(panel);
//
  var submitHandler = app.createServerHandler("next");
  subbtn.addClickHandler(submitHandler);
  submitHandler.addCallbackElement(panel);
//
  app.add(panel);  
  ss.show(app);
  }
//
function click(e){
   var row=ss.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();              
   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   var txtBox = app.getElementById("item");
   var subbtn = app.getElementById("next").setText("next ?")      
   var txt0=app.getElementById("lab0").setText('--');
   var txt1=app.getElementById("lab1").setText('no match').setStyleAttribute("background", "white");// default value to start with
   var txt2=app.getElementById("lab2").setText('');
   var item=e.parameter.item.toLowerCase(); // item to search for
   var hidden=app.getElementById("hidden")                  
   var data = sh.getRange(2,1,lastrow,8).getValues();// get the 8 columns of data
       for(nn=0;nn<data.length;++nn){ ;// iterate trough
         if(data[nn].toString().toLowerCase().match(item.toString())==item.toString()&&item!=''){;// if a match is found in one of the 3 fields, break the loop and show results
            var datarow=data[nn]                                                                                    
              for(cc=0;cc<datarow.length;++cc){
                if(datarow[cc].toString().toLowerCase().match(item.toString())==item.toString()&&item!=''){break}
              }
           var idx=cc                                                                                      
          txt0.setText(nn+2);
          txt1.setText(data[nn][idx]).setStyleAttribute("background", "cyan");
          txt2.setText(data[nn][idx+1]);
          sh.getRange(nn+2,idx+1).activate();
          subbtn.setText("found '"+item+"' in row "+Number(nn+2)+", next ?");
          hidden.setValue(nn.toString())                                                                                  
          break
          }
      }
return app    ;// update UI
}
function next(e){
   var row=ss.getActiveRange().getRowIndex();              
   var app = UiApp.getActiveApplication();
   var txtBox = app.getElementById("item");
   var subbtn = app.getElementById("next").setText("no other match")      
   var hidden=app.getElementById("hidden");                  
   var start=Number(e.parameter.hidden)+1;//returns the last search index stored in the UI
   var item=e.parameter.item.toLowerCase(); // item to search for
   var txt0=app.getElementById("lab0");
   var txt1=app.getElementById("lab1").setStyleAttribute("background", "yellow");
   var txt2=app.getElementById("lab2");
   var data = sh.getRange(2,1,lastrow,8).getValues();// get the 3 columns of data
       for(nn=start;nn<data.length;++nn){ ;// iterate trough
         if(data[nn].toString().toLowerCase().match(item.toString())==item.toString()&&item!=''){;// if a match is found in one of the 3 fields, break the loop and show results
            var datarow=data[nn]                                                                                    
              for(cc=0;cc<datarow.length;++cc){
                if(datarow[cc].toString().toLowerCase().match(item.toString())==item.toString()&&item!=''){break}
              }
           var idx=cc                                                                                      
          txt0.setText(nn+2);
          txt1.setText(data[nn][idx]).setStyleAttribute("background", "cyan");
          txt2.setText(data[nn][idx+1]);
          sh.getRange(nn+2,idx+1).activate();
          subbtn.setText("found '"+item+"' in row "+Number(nn+2)+", next ?");                                                                                               
          hidden.setValue(nn.toString())                                                                                  
          break
          }
      }
return app    ;// update UI
}
//
function gendoclisttest(){
  sh.getRange(1,1).setValue('.');// usefull to allow for 'clear' if page is empty
  sh.getRange(1,1,ss.getLastRow(),ss.getLastColumn()).clear().setWrap(false).setBorder(false,false,false,false,false,false);// clears whole sheet
  var doclist=new Array();
  var folders=DocsList.getFolders()
  for(ff=0;ff<folders.length;++ff){
    doclist=folders[ff].getFiles(0,2000)
    var names = new Array();
      for (nn=0;nn<doclist.length;++nn){
      names.push([doclist[nn].getName(),doclist[nn].getId()]);
      }
  if (names.length>0){
    names.sort();
    var row=ss.getLastRow()+1;
    sh.getRange(row,1,1,3).setValues([["Folders","Generic Doc Names","ID"]]).setBorder(false,true,true,true,true,true).setBackgroundColor("#dddddd");
    sh.getRange(row+1,1).setValue(folders[ff].getName())
    sh.getRange(row+1,2,names.length,2).setValues(names);
  }
    }
    doclist=DocsList.getRootFolder().getFiles(0,2000)
    var names = new Array();
      for (nn=0;nn<doclist.length;++nn){
      names.push([doclist[nn].getName(),doclist[nn].getId()]);
      }
  if (names.length>0){
    names.sort();
    var row=ss.getLastRow()+1;
    sh.getRange(row,1,1,3).setValues([["Root","Generic Doc Names","ID"]]).setBorder(false,true,true,true,true,true).setBackgroundColor("#dddddd");
    sh.getRange(row+1,2,names.length,2).setValues(names);
    }
}
//
function doclistcat(){
  var doclist=new Array();
  var folders=DocsList.getFolders()
  var zz=0;var nn=0
  for(ff=0;ff<folders.length;++ff){
    doclist=folders[ff].getFilesByType("spreadsheet",0,2000);
    var names = new Array();
      for (nn=0;nn<doclist.length;++nn){
      names.push([doclist[nn].getName(),doclist[nn].getId()]);
      }
 if(names.length>0){
    names.sort();
    zz=zz+nn
    var row=zz-nn+1
    sh.getRange(row,4,1,3).setValues([["Folders","Spreadsheet Names","ID"]]).setBorder(true,true,true,true,true,true).setBackgroundColor("#dddddd");
    sh.getRange(row+1,4).setValue(folders[ff].getName()).setB
    sh.getRange(row+1,5,names.length,2).setValues(names);
    }
    }
    doclist=DocsList.getRootFolder().getFilesByType("spreadsheet",0,2000);
    var names = new Array();
      for (nn=0;nn<doclist.length;++nn){
      names.push([doclist[nn].getName(),doclist[nn].getId()]);
      }
 if(names.length>0){
    names.sort();
    zz=zz+nn
    var row=zz-nn+1
    sh.getRange(row,4,1,3).setValues([["Root","Spreadsheet Names","ID"]]).setBorder(true,true,true,true,true,true).setBackgroundColor("#dddddd");
    sh.getRange(row+1,5,names.length,2).setValues(names);
    }
//
  var zz=0;var nn=0
  for(ff=0;ff<folders.length;++ff){
    doclist=folders[ff].getFilesByType("document",0,2000);
    var names = new Array();
      for (nn=0;nn<doclist.length;++nn){
      names.push([doclist[nn].getName(),doclist[nn].getId()]);
      }
 if(names.length>0){
    names.sort();
    zz=zz+nn
    var row=zz-nn+1
    sh.getRange(row,7,1,3).setValues([["Folders","Text Document Names","ID"]]).setBorder(true,true,true,true,true,true).setBackgroundColor("#dddddd");
    sh.getRange(row+1,7).setValue(folders[ff].getName()).setB
    sh.getRange(row+1,8,names.length,2).setValues(names);
    }
    }
    doclist=DocsList.getRootFolder().getFilesByType("document",0,2000);
    var names = new Array();
      for (nn=0;nn<doclist.length;++nn){
      names.push([doclist[nn].getName(),doclist[nn].getId()]);
      }
 if(names.length>0){
    names.sort();
    zz=zz+nn
    var row=zz-nn+1
    sh.getRange(row,7,1,3).setValues([["Root","document Names","ID"]]).setBorder(true,true,true,true,true,true).setBackgroundColor("#dddddd");
    sh.getRange(row+1,8,names.length,2).setValues(names);
    }  
}
// 
//eof
```

Comment: Thank you so much. Worked perfectly!